# Insert document inside another document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

how can I insert a document inside another document with mongodb ?

I've tried something like the code below but I always have a problem converting my list of setting in the field Settings:

```
var settingViewModels = new[]{ setting };
var query = Query.EQ("Name", applicationName);
var update = Update.AddToSet("Settings", BsonArray.Create(setting));
db.Collection<Applications>().Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Upsert, SafeMode.True)
```

I got an error when I convert my settingViewModels into BsonArray saying:

.NET type MyProject.SettingViewModel cannot be mapped into BsonType.Array
Parameter name: value

Any idea ?

thanks
John

Comment: What is type of setting variable?

Comment: here's setting's object:

    public class SettingViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want add setting item to the Settings[] array of Application collection you should use `ToBsonDocument()` extention method from `MongoDB.Bson` namespace:

```
var update = Update.AddToSet("Settings", setting.ToBsonDocument());
```

You no need create `BsonArray`.

Comment: Hi, I've tried your solution and i get a new error:

Safemode detected an error: Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array (response: { "err" : "Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array", "code" : 12591, "n" : 0, "connectionId" : 1174, "ok" : 1 })

Here's my copy paste of your code:

    var query = Query.EQ("Name", applicationName);
    var update = Update.AddToSet("Settings", setting.ToBsonDocument());
db.Collection<Applications>().Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Upsert, SafeMode.True)

Comment: @JohnSmith: This is because 'Settings' field not array in your application document, but should be.. Can you update your question with 'Application' document example?

Comment: Andrew, you'are the king of mongodb